# Force all nhibernate proxies to be load for an instance

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-evaluation, proxy-classes

I want to take a snapshot of an instance of an entity and therefore I want to force all proxies to load for this instance.

I don't want to disable lazy loading for the majority of the time I just wondering if there is an API I can call to force all proxies to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is a utility function `NHibernateUtil.Initialize(object)` which is not recursive if i remember correctly. With the help of `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(object)` you can create a method of your own that loads all proxies in an oject

Answer (score 2):

There is a [lazy initializer for NHibernate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHibernateLazyInitializer.aspx) on codeproject that should be able to accomplish this.